# Wildcard backup MySQL databases

Tags: mysql

There are quite a few discussion on the Interweb on how to backup based on the wildcard `table name`, but how about wildcard `database name`?

e.g.

If I have databases named

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
 .
 .
fooN
bar1
```

I want to only backup db with name prefixed `foo`, is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You select database names from `tables` table in `information_schema` database. you can use filter to filter by your prefix. the use outputed database names to export using mysqldump. a practical example is as follows:

```
mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD --databases $(
  mysql -uroot -p -N information_schema \
    -e "SELECT DISTINCT(TABLE_SCHEMA)
        FROM tables
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'prefix%'"
) > /tmp/backup.sql
```